# What is the .NET equivalent of Java's NumberFormatException?

Tags: java, .net, formatexception, numberformatexception

Is FormatException in .NET the equivalent of NumberFormatException in Java ?

Comment: I think ***YES***. Haven't you tried to read/search it on net?

Answer (score 8):

I think yes both are same following are the details given about both Exception

**NumberFormatException** (java) : -Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have the appropriate format.

**FormatException** (.net) : - FormatException is thrown when the format of an argument in a method invocation does not match the format of the corresponding formal parameter type. For example, if a method specifies a String parameter consisting of two digits with an embedded period, passing a corresponding string argument containing only two digits to that method would cause FormatException to be thrown.

FormatException uses the HRESULT COR_E_FORMAT, which has the value 0x80131537.

refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formatexception.aspx

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Methods like [`Double.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt.aspx) throw a FormatException if the string to be converted does not represent a number in a valid format.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [`FormatException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formatexception.aspx) is thrown when you try to parse a number from a string with an invalid format (actually it's limited to numbers).